# Python- row to new column mapping

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am stuck in doing row to column transformatio. Can anyone help me with the logic.[transformation to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN3tB.jpg)

Basically every 3 rows is to be processed at once and convert it into one row by mapping rows data to column in python.

Please reply.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you specifically need help with? Show us some code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.